# Days get only past 7 days data in List android-sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created an app that uses Sqlite database. I want to display the data from today to 7 days past. Data above that should not be selected. So for that I had written a query, but it doesn't seem to be working. In the list I am getting data above past 7 days also

Code

```
public ArrayList<DbModel> getRecentDocs() {
        database = getWritableDatabase();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date date = new Date();
        String todate = dateFormat.format(date);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
        Date todate1 = cal.getTime();
        String fromdate = dateFormat.format(todate1);
        alGetRecentFiles = new ArrayList<DbModel>();
        dbModel = new DbModel();
        String query = "Select * From " + saveFileTable + " where " + postedOn + " >= " + fromdate;
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            dbModel = new DbModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(userId)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(docId)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(fileName)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(fileExt)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(title)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(filePath)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(postedOn)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(favourite)));
            alGetRecentFiles.add(dbModel);
        }
        c.close();
        database.close();
        return alGetRecentFiles;
    }
```

Comment: So what data does your Query return? Is it a problem with the Query or the list?

Comment: ya its the query the query